# log4j on EB does not send application logs to Amazon Cloud watch

Tags: log4j, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using a custom log4j AWS log appender (https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders) to write my application logs to Amazon cloud watch.

When I run the application from my box, I can see logs have been successfully sent to Amazon cloud watch.

However, when I deploy the application to Amazon ElasticBeans, it does not work.

Any help?

Comment: Not sure if you got a notification, but I added comments to the [issue](https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders/issues/34) that you raised. Short answer: I believe that you'll need to add permissions to the execution role that you're using for Elastic Beanstalk (see [doc](https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders/blob/master/docs/cloudwatch.md#permissions)). If that doesn't work I'm happy to work through the issue either there or here.

Comment: Hey @Mohammed Elrasheed I am trying to push data from outside of AWS into AWS Cloudwatch, but it does not work. From what I see, this case is fine for you, did you have to enable any permissions on AWS side?